# How can I delete a remote file from bitbucket using eclipse?

Tags: bitbucket, egit

I've wrongly added some useless files to a bitbucket repository. Now, I'd like to delete these files from the remote repository, but not from the local one. These files are already added to .gitignore.
Is this delete operation possible using eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in eclipse but here's how to do it in bitbucket.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/293052/how-to-delete-a-filefolder-from-bitbucket-repository

```
remote repository's website > Source > select branch > select folder > select file to be deleted > Edit > Delete > Commit.
```

Don't push those files the next time and make sure they are added to the gitignore.

Comment: What if I haven't a branch yet?

Comment: Then you're on your master branch

Comment: yep, sorry, I hadn't understood well your step. Well, it's a lot of work to delete all files one at time. I'll wait for other answers and if it's the only working solution, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you want to do. But normally if you don't want those files track next time add them to your gitignore stop tracking those files and commit + push.

Comment: from your link, I reached [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/2326627) answer; AkiraYamamoto 's method made my day.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have cloned the bitbucket repository using EGIT

In Eclipse using EGIT:

- delete the file in the path of the cloned repository.
  Ex: C:/<-Path to your repository->/FiletoDelete
- Refresh
- Open the Git Staging View
- Stage the file & Commit the file deletion
- Push this commit to the remote repository